# org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.data-source."DSMySql" is already registered?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, datasource

Why I am getting these errors:

org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.data-source."DSMySql" is already registered?

MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject-app.war".INSTALL

web.xml file:

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:/DSMySql</name>
    <class-name>org.omnifaces.persistence.datasource.SwitchableXADataSource</class-name>
    <property>
        <name>configFile</name>
        <value>datasource-settings.xml</value> <!-- Driver/url/user/password are defined over there. -->
    </property>
    <transactional>true</transactional>
    <isolation-level>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</isolation-level>
    <initial-pool-size>2</initial-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-statements>0</max-statements>
</data-source>
```

persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="kickoff">
    <jta-data-source>java:/DSMySql</jta-data-source>

    <mapping-file>META-INF/LoginToken.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/User.xml</mapping-file>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap" value="false" /> <!-- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2727 -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have already created the datasource `java:/DSMySql` inside WildFly server.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have already created the datasource java:/DSMySql inside WildFly server.*

There is your answer. You've already configured it in server end. You don't need to duplicate it in webapp end. They will only collide with each other.

Get rid of `<data-source>` in `web.xml` (or the server-configured one) and all should be well.

Comment: If I removed it from the server, I get an error saying that could not create the pool named DSMySql ??

Comment: `<data-source>` inside `web.xml` I have defined connection settings inside `datasource-settings.xml`, but if I renamed the data source, or removing it from server, that will cause an error saying unable to create connection, or pool named... not found.

Comment: `<jta-data-source>` I have to create that datasource in server side.
For `<data-source>` the configuration is inside that xml file. I used MySQL database.